# R: Dataframe summary into a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, charts

I'm really new into R and I'm working on a solution that needs to handle dataframe and charts.

I have an original DF like the one below:

```
Product_ID  Sales_2016  Sales_2017  Import
1   1162.91 235.19  1
2   1191.11 944.87  1
3   1214.96 737.06  0
4   1336.07 986.15  0
5   1343.29 871.33  1
6   1208.78 1168.82 0
7   1205.49 900.39  0
8   1675.69 2255.11 0
9   1412.55 1021.05 1
10  1546.06 1893.82 0
11  1393.98 1629.42 0
12  1264.76 1014.74 0
13  1399    2163.64 0
14  1712.75 1845.59 0
15  1310.67 1400.31 1
16  1727.8  1574.98 0
17  1987.14 3359.82 0
18  1711.99 2065.15 0
19  1570.97 2444.15 0
20  1546.2  1912.32 0
```

I want to build a stack bar chart with this data where it should show the year (2020/2021) on the X axis and the sales sum on the Y axis. The bar would split imported or not into two groups and stack them like the image bellow:

[image]

TO achieve it, my solution was to create another DF manually with the sum values:

```
Import   TotalSales   Year
1        123456       2016
0        654321       2016
1        456789       2017
0        987654       2017
```

I created this DF totally manually. My question is, is there a faster and more reliable way to create this chart and this kind of dataframe view?

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: Convert wide-to-long, then plot.

Comment: As zx8754 notes, you should convert wide to long, aggregate by year and import, and then plot. The duplicates targets show you how to do each step.